# SELECT without grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How get results without grouping it?

My table

```
id  user_id amount  currency_id type    status
5   2   2.00    1   0   0
6   3   3.00    1   0   0
4   1   1.00    1   0   0
7   4   4.00    1   0   0
8   5   3.00    1   1   0
```

I do the following select

```
SELECT id, user_id, amount, currency_id, SUM( amount ) 
FROM market
WHERE amount <=3
AND type = 0
AND status = 0
```

Result:

```
id  user_id amount  currency_id SUM( amount )
5   2   2.00    1   6.00
```

How get this result:

```
id  user_id amount  currency_id SUM( amount )
5   2   2.00    1   0   6.00
6   3   3.00    1   0   6.00
4   1   1.00    1   0   6.00
```

Comment: If you don't want to `GROUP`, don't use `SUM()`.  Are you trying to get the total sum of all records in the query? I guess I don't see where that `6.00` for each row comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to return individual records that meet this criteria AND sum them up and you don't actually need the SUM value as a field on every row (not sure why you would), then I would suggest looking at the `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` modifier.  It works like this:

```
SELECT id, user_id, SUM(amount) AS `amounts`, currency_id
FROM market
WHERE amount <=3
AND type = 0
AND status = 0
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
```

Here I am grouping by `id` because this will keep the individual records intact as this value is unique

You output would look like this:

```
id    user_id amounts  currency_id
5     2       2.00    1
6     3       3.00    1
4     1       1.00    1
NULL  3       6.00    1
```

Note the last record provides the rollup to the `SUM()` function. Also note that values for `user_id` and `currency_id` in the rollup row are indeterminate as they were not part of the GROUP BY or aggregation. As such, they have no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You can do join

```
SELECT  id, 
        user_id, 
        amount, 
        currency_id, 
        a.totalAmount
FROM    market
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT SUM(amount) totalAmount
            FROM    market
            WHERE   amount <=3
                    AND type = 0 
                    AND status = 0
        ) a
WHERE   amount <=3
        AND type = 0 
        AND status = 0
```

or using inline subquery,

```
SELECT  id, 
        user_id, 
        amount, 
        currency_id, 
        (
            SELECT SUM(amount) totalAmount
            FROM    market
            WHERE   amount <=3
                    AND type = 0 
                    AND status = 0
        ) totalAmount
FROM    market
WHERE   amount <=3
        AND type = 0 
        AND status = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT id, user_id, amount, currency_id, t2.total
FROM market, (
    SELECT SUM(amount) AS total
    FROM market
    WHERE amount <=3
    AND type = 0
    AND status = 0
) AS t2
WHERE amount <=3
AND type = 0
AND status = 0
```